# unexpected changes in member variables of an object

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures

I have this code in C++:

```
void printHeap (Heap<T> &heap)
{
    typename list< HeapNode<T> >::iterator heapIterator = heap.heap.begin();

    for( ; heapIterator != heap.heap.end(); ++heapIterator)
    {
        cout<<"element"<<endl;
    }
}
```

And this is the definition of a Heap:

```
template <class T>
class Heap
{

public:

    list <HeapNode<T> > heap;
    HeapNode<T> *minValue;

    BinomialHeap(HeapNode<T> *min = 0)
    {
        minValue = min;
    }

    T getMinimumKey()
    {
        return minValue->key;
    }

    void insert(T data)
    {
        HeapNode<T> tmp (data);
        heap.push_back(tmp);
        if(!minValue || minValue->key > tmp.key)
            minValue = &tmp;
    }
};
```

HeapNode.cpp
template

```
class HeapNode
{
public:
    int degree;
    HeapNode<T> *parent;
    list <HeapNode<T> *> sons;
    T key;
    HeapNode(T d, HeapNode<T> *parent = 0)
    {
        key = d;
        this->parent = parent;
        degree = 0;
    }
};
```

I have tried this code, but I am getting some unexpected values:

```
BinomialHeap<int> heap;
heap.insert(4);
heap.insert(3);
heap.insert(2);
heap.insert(1);
cout<<heap.getMinimumKey() <<endl;
printHeap(heap);
cout<<heap.getMinimumKey();
```

The first cout prints 1 (as expected), but after calling printHeap, minValue changes even though I did not manipulate this member variable (the second cout prints a weird number). Why is it happening? Shouldn't it print the same number, since I am not modifying minValue in that method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void insert(T data)
{
    HeapNode<T> tmp (data);
    heap.push_back(tmp);
    if(!minValue || minValue->key > tmp.key)
        minValue = &tmp;
}
```

This code is broken. You create a temporary object, then you stash a pointer to it. But as soon as the function returns, the object ceases to exist, so the pointer points to nothing. When you call `getMinimumKey`, you get garbage. I think you wanted to set `minValue` to point to the copy of `tmp` you pushed onto the list.

Comment: Thanks, if I want to point to the element in the list? is there a way to access to that element? will be minValue = &(*heap.end()) a good solution?

Comment: `list::back()` (or your suggestion). But don't forget, you have to account for this correctly in your copy constructor and copy assignment operator. (Or, for C++11, delete them. For earlier version of C++, make them private and don't ever use them.)

Comment: If I understand the code properly, then the `parent` and `sons` pointers are all going to have the same issue; so it would be wise to make sure the heap is non-copyable and non-moveable and great care is taken when an item is removed from it

Comment: @MattMcNabb One valuable lesson one can learn from this kind of thing is that bare pointers are almost never the right solution in C++.

Comment: @David yeah, although I can't think of a simple O(1) solution to use instead of those pointers, unless he totally redesigns the structure (e.g. actually use a heap structure, instead of a flat list with a pointer web)

Comment: Maybe an option that still keeps the flat list of nodes would just be to use a vector of nodes; and use integer indices instead of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

> but after calling printHeap, minValue changes

That usually indicates you are doing an out of bounds array access, or accessing through an invalid pointer.

```
void insert(T data)
{
    HeapNode<T> tmp (data);
    heap.push_back(tmp);
    if(!minValue || minValue->key > tmp.key)
        minValue = &tmp;
}
```

And here it is... `tmp` is local to this function, and it ceases to exist when the function exits, leaving `minValue` as a wild pointer.

To fix this you will either have to make `minValue` point at something which is guaranteed to not be destroyed so long as `minValue` is not changed; or implement your minvalue-finder in some other way.

You *could* make `minValue` point at an actual list element, however that is still dangerous unless you also check `minValue` at every possible other point where the list may have nodes removed from it. You'd also have to account for `minValue` in the copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator; the default versions of those would no longer work (they'd leave minValue as a bogus pointer again).

Comment: Thank you, even though I didn't choose your answer, I appreciate your help.